# How to color table rows according to a specific input dynamically?

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, ajax

I am just starting to learn about javascript, jquery , and ajax.

I really need help knowing the logic or how I should approach this problem:

I have a table of " expenses" that could be monthly :

```
      Type     Cost     Monthly/yearly
      Laundry    2000$     Monthly
      Groceries    300$    Monthly
      Clothes    100$    Monthly
```

I have an input `budget` . What I need is that say the user inputted `200$` , the rows whose cost is greater than the budget AND that are monthly should be coloured in red:

```
 Type     Cost     Monthly/yearly
  Laundry    2000$     Monthly (colored in red)
  Groceries    300$    Monthly (colored in red)
  Clothes    100$    Monthly
```

But then the user can input another `budget` , and then the colors in the table should update automatically. Now he inputs `1000$` :

```
Type     Cost     Monthly/yearly
      Laundry    2000$     Monthly ( only one colored in red)
      Groceries    300$    Monthly 
      Clothes    100$    Monthly
```

How can I achieve that? I just need to know how to approach this logic wise. I'm using Node.Js

Comment: I suggest you add any code or attempts you have made so far.

Comment: again , I'm asking for the logic as I'm lacking any way of how to APPROACH this problem.  I'm an R programmer, this is a whole new territory to me

Comment: where do you generate your table? in JS or in htmll? As in where is your data held. This will dictate a proper approach

Comment: Is it all server side or would you rather have client logic? this will also dictate a possible approach

Comment: Can you, at the *very* least, show the HTML of the relevant element(s)? We're here to *help* with your problems, not to solve them for you.

Answer (score 1):

man if you post us onyl your ideas, without any piece of actual code, we can't really help you. I only give you and advice: you could check with javascript the value of your input box and if it's greater/lesser than X, colour it (with "style" attribute) via Javascript. Example

```
<input type="text" id="boo" onfocusout="colourbox()">
```

in your head tag, just write some js code

```
<script>
function colourbox(){
var boo = document.getElementById("boo");
if(boo.value > 200)
    boo.style="background-color:red";
}
</script>
```

this code colours red your input box in case of it contains a value greater than 200. Hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

I will try and give you a bit of very weird pseudocode. Hope it helps
 I will give you the explanation of two possible approaches a client side and a server side version. There is also some notes on what you might use.

It might be in your best interest to try both approaches wich may come in handy down the road.

---

**CLIENT SIDE VERSION:**

**CSS**

Create a CSS class that styles your background and font color, lets say danger, works for either approach. You should also style the td inside the rows

**HTML**

Create your input and put a name on it lets say the name is budget
Create your table with all the data

**JS**

Lets say you want to change the coloring whenever the input field changes
First you will need to capture the changes on the field input. You can use the [on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) function of jquery

- When you capture the change event    [Remove the danger class](https://api.jquery.com/removeclass/) from
  all of the rows

  - Get the value of the input
  - Iterate through each row
  - Get the numeric value of the cost cell. Use [parseInt](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parseint.asp) or
    [parseFloat](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_parsefloat.asp) to get the numeric value.If needed remove commas or $
    sign using [replace()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_replace.asp)
  - Get the text value of the the
    Monthly/Yearly
  - check if your cost numeric values is bigger than budget and that the text value is equals to Monthly
  - If the condition is true [add the class](https://api.jquery.com/addclass/) danger to the current row using addClass()

---

**SERVER SIDE VERSION:**

Since you are working server side I assume you have the data in variables or ina an array. Lets say you have an array of objects, along the lines of

```
var array = [
    {type: 'laundry',cost: 200, repetition: 'monthly'},
    {type: 'food',cost: 100, repetition: 'monthly'},
    ...
]
```

and your budget

```
var budget = 200;
```

**CSS**

Create a CSS class that styles your background and font color, lets say danger, works for either approach. You should also style the td inside the rows.

**SERVER GENERATED VIEW**

- You will need to iterate through every element of array
- in each iteration you will create a row with the following data
- if cost < budget and repetition == 'monthly' then you should add the danger
  class to the row
- add the type cell to the row
- add the cost cell to the row
- add the repetition cell to the row

Comment: Sorry but these are ideas. I will not post any code. Once you  @momo12321 has tried generating some code we will truly be able to help you